# How to detect if the language is English (All variants) on Android?

Tags: android, locale

I want to show a button only for English users, is there a way to detect the language settings?

I know how to get the current `Locale`, but I don't know if comparing it against `Locale.English` is sufficient, since there must be a lot of English variations etc.

Anyone experience doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device/23168383#23168383

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() will give your default language of your device
```

### Example

```
System.out.println("My locale::"+Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
```

### Result

My locale::English

Answer (score 28):

From the [`Locale` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html):

> The language codes are two-letter lowercase ISO language codes (such as "en") as defined by ISO 639-1. The country codes are two-letter uppercase ISO country codes (such as "US") as defined by ISO 3166-1.

This means that

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")
```

should be `true`. I'd be careful with hiding/showing UI only by default `Locale` though. Many countries may have many users that prefer another language, but are perfectly fluent in English.

Comment: But is there a possibility to only get `en` instead of English?

Comment: @MaxAllan It's not only a possibility, that's the intent of this code. That's why I'm comparing to `"en"`. This is preferrable especially in the general case in my opinion because then you don't have to think or worry about cases like "Español" vs. "Spanish", etc. There's a universally accepted language code for Spanish: `es`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part, but in the case that I would like to select rows from a database where the column `lang = 'sv'` for Swedish, how will I do then? If the UI is in Swedish.

Comment: @MaxAllan  Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("sv")

Comment: it can be Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().contains("en") to check all varient of english

Answer (score 5):

What about using Java's startsWith() function to check whether the current locale is an English variant or not.

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().startsWith("en")
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution would be to create a localized English version of the form. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is probably:

```
boolean def_english = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language().equals(Locale.ENGLISH.getISO3Language());
```

Answer (score 1):

All I can say about language is that :

1- in order to get the current language of app itself you should use

String CurrentLang = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();

2- in order to get the current language of the device you should use

String CurrentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

Comment: This is useful information; however, it doesn't answer the OP's question of, how to tell whether it is a *variant* of English, i.e. en-GB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To know if the default language is an english variant (en_GB or en_AU or en_IN or en_US) then try this

```
if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals(new Locale("en").getLanguage())) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Language is English");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();`

```
if(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage().equals("English")){

    //do something
}
```