# How to format a Float Value with the device currency format?

Tags: android, localization, locale

I have an app that prints a calculated money value and I want to display that value with the default currency format.

For example in Europe you would write:

1.000,95€

In the US I think you would write

1,000.95$

In other currencies there are more or less values displayed for the decimal fraction, in US it would be 2 but in Japan it would be 0.

How can I obtain a exact as possible format for all existing currencies?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I found the solution. THe class [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) has a multitude of predefined formatters. There is also one for formatting currency Values.

If you use the static method getCurrencyInstance the class will return a formatter for the device default currency. I use the following code to set my result:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_result)).setText(format.format(result));
```

Comment: what will happen in the case result = 1000, and your phone locale is FR, but you are in the US? Will it write 1 000 € instead of $1,000?  The currency format is not going to account for conversion or result correct?

Comment: @paul_hundal it depends on your device's locale/language, and it does not matter the (physical) location

Answer (score 88):

For sake of completeness suppose you want to display a price in phone's current locale (correct decimal mark and thousand separator) but with a currency of your choice.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("CZK"));
String result = format.format(1234567.89);
```

`result` would then hold these values:

- `CZK1,234,567.89` with US locale
- `1 234 567,89 Kč` with Czech locale

If you'd like to omit the decimal part for prices (show `$199` instead of `$199.00`) call this before using the formatter:

```
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
```

All options are listed in [`NumberFormat` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: This link helpful for Locale  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device?rq=1

Comment: In case somebody has issues in getting correct currency symbols, here an alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777689/how-to-get-numberformat-instance-from-currency-code

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`DecimalFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

> It has a variety of features designed to make it possible to parse and
>   format numbers in any locale, including support for Western, Arabic,
>   or Indic digits. It also supports different flavors of numbers,
>   including integers ("123"), fixed-point numbers ("123.4"), scientific
>   notation ("1.23E4"), percentages ("12%"), **and currency amounts
>   ("$123"). All of these flavors can be easily localized.**

Comment: Perfect pointer for me, because I wanted to show the currency as "USD 100.00" or "100,00 USD", depending on the device's Locale.

Answer (score 2):

to get device locale you could use this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static Locale getCurrentLocale(Context c) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return c.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return c.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
```

and then to do format:

```
        double num = 1323.526;

        NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getCurrentLocale(getContext()));
        defaultFormat.format(num)
```

Comment: `locale` is equal to `getLocales().get(0)`. Or there's [ConfigurationCompat#getLocales](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/ConfigurationCompat). There's no need to do this yourself.