# How to get NumberFormat instance from currency code?

Tags: java

How can I get a `NumberFormat` (or `DecimalFormat`) instance corresponding to an ISO 4217 currency code (such as "EUR" or "USD") in order to format prices correctly?

> **Note 1:** The problem I'm having is that the `NumberFormat`/`DecimalFormat` classes have a
>   `getCurrencyInstance(Locale locale)` method but I can't figure out how
>   to get to a `Locale` object from an ISO 4217 currency code.
>
> **Note 2:** There is also a `java.util.Currency` class which has a `getInstance(String currencyCode)` method (returning the `Currency`
>   instance for a given ISO 4217 currency code) but again I can't figure
>   out how to get from a `Currency` object to a `NumberFormat`
>   instance...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood this correctly, but you could try something like:

```
public class CurrencyTest
{
    @Test
    public void testGetNumberFormatForCurrencyCode()
    {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("USD");
        format.setCurrency(currency);

        System.out.println(format.format(1234.23434));
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
1,234.23
```

Notice that I set the maximum amount of fractional digits separately, the [NumberFormat.setCurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setCurrency%28java.util.Currency%29) doesn't touch the maximum amount of fractional digits:

> Sets the currency used by this number format when formatting currency
>   values. This does not update the minimum or maximum number of fraction
>   digits used by the number format.

Comment: This solution is not ideal as currencies sometimes show up in the format "CA$0.69" instead of "$0.69" as alluded to by Spencer Kormos, but found this solution to be the simplest and cleanest, and need to press on, so went with it. Just made one change – instead of making the call `format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);`, I’m making the call `format.setMaximumFractionDigits(currency.getDefaultFractionDigits());` instead.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` instead of just `getInstance()`.

Comment: I suppose this is intended for `import java.text.NumberFormat;` and not `import android.icu.text.NumberFormat;`. It seems setMaximumFractionDigits and setCurrency from NumberFormat in android.icu.text.NumberFormat will work only with minimum API level 24.

Comment: @esaj, what changes would be required to show `$` with the output number as the currency format is "USD"? (wish to get output like `$1,234.23`)

Answer (score 6):

The mapping is sometimes one to many... Like the euro is used in many countries (locales)...

Just because the currency code is the same the format might be different as this example shows:

```
private static Collection<Locale> getLocalesFromIso4217(String iso4217code) {
    Collection<Locale> returnValue = new LinkedList<Locale>();
    for (Locale locale : NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
        String code = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).
        getCurrency().getCurrencyCode();
        if (iso4217code.equals(code)) {
            returnValue.add(locale);
        }
    }  
    return returnValue;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getLocalesFromIso4217("USD"));
    System.out.println(getLocalesFromIso4217("EUR"));
    for (Locale locale : getLocalesFromIso4217("EUR")) {
        System.out.println(locale + "=>" + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(1234));
    }
}
```

Output

```
[en_US, es_US, es_EC, es_PR]
[pt_PT, el_CY, fi_FI, en_MT, sl_SI, ga_IE, fr_BE, es_ES, de_AT, nl_NL, el_GR, it_IT, en_IE, fr_LU, nl_BE, ca_ES, sr_ME, mt_MT, fr_FR, de_DE, de_LU]

pt_PT=>1.234,00 €
el_CY=>€1.234,00
fi_FI=>1 234,00 €
en_MT=>€1,234.00
sl_SI=>€ 1.234
ga_IE=>€1,234.00
fr_BE=>1.234,00 €
es_ES=>1.234,00 €
de_AT=>€ 1.234,00
nl_NL=>€ 1.234,00
el_GR=>1.234,00 €
it_IT=>€ 1.234,00
en_IE=>€1,234.00
fr_LU=>1 234,00 €
nl_BE=>1.234,00 €
ca_ES=>€ 1.234,00
sr_ME=>€ 1.234,00
mt_MT=>€1,234.00
fr_FR=>1 234,00 €
de_DE=>1.234,00 €
de_LU=>1.234,00 €
```

Answer (score 6):

Locale can be used both to get the standard currency for the Locale and to print *any* currency symbol properly in the locale you specify. These are two distinct operations, and not really related.

From the [Java Internationalization tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html), you first get an instance of the Currency using either the Locale or the ISO code. Then you can print the symbol using *another* Locale. So if you get the US Currency from the en_US Locale, and call getSymbol() it will print "$". But if you call getSymbol(Locale) with the British Locale, it will print "USD".

So if you don't care what your current user's locale is, and you just care about the currencies, then you can ignore the Locale in all cases.

If you care about representing the currency symbol correctly based on your current user, then you need to get the Locale *of the user* specific to the user's location.

Comment: Like esaj mentions, the Currency and not the Locale is what sets the decimal places to format. The Locale is just how to display the currency symbol and decimal separator.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, though I've never used it, you might want to give [Joda Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/) a try. If it's as good as Joda-Time, it probably is easier and more powerful than the standard JDK stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following method:

```
private static NumberFormat getNumberFormat(String currencyCode)
{
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);

    Locale[] locales = NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales();

    for (Locale locale : locales)
    {
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

        if (numberFormat.getCurrency() == currency)
            return numberFormat;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Bernard. Unfortunately, as pointed out by Adam,  there's a problem in that a given currency code can map to multiple locales...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PriceHelper {
    public static String formatPrice(Context context, String currencyCode, 
                                      double price) {
        if (price == 0) {
            return context.getString(R.string.free);
        }
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        format.setCurrency(currency);
        return format.format(price);
    }
}
```