# Formatting currency based on currency code

Tags: java, android, formatting, currency, currency-formatting

I have a list of currencies, let's make it simple and say `{USD, CAD, EUR, VND}` (but in reality we support 40 currencies). I want to be able to format numbers properly, based on these currency codes.

Requirements:

**1.** decimal separators and symbol placement (left or right of number) must be based on currency code:

> "USD" -> $1,200.45 (no matter what language and region the phone is
>   using, the formatting should be the one of the "biggest" country using this currency code, in this case USA)

**EDIT:** this was solved by manually building hashmap of String->Locale, see @David Conrad's comment.

**2.** symbol must always be symbol and not letters:

> "USD" -> "$" (not "US$" or "USD")
>    "CAD" -> "$" (not "CA$" or "CAD")
>    "VND" -> "₫" ...

I am using my custom font where I made sure to include all the supported symbols.

---

I tried with `getNumberInstance` (and `getCurrencyInstance`) [[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777944/1181261)], but it doesn't work on all phones (some phones show "US$" instead of just "$"). <strike>I tried building a hashmap to link currency codes to Locales [[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777956/1181261)], but it's a one-to-many relation so it is not reliable.</strike>

I am now on the brink to try out [Joda Money](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money) or even [JavaMoney/jsr354-api](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api) but after research both of these libraries has their own quirks and if possible I'd like to avoid including any additional lib.

So, how do we do this?

Comment: How is it a one-to-many relation? You said you want to just use the biggest country for each currency code, so just put one for each currency in the map.

Comment: You are correct, and I already built the map manually. But still, on some phones I get "US$" instead of "$". Or "руб" instad of "₽".