# How to format a number as currency using only currency code?

Tags: android, number-formatting

My business problem is as follows: I have a currency code (e.g. "USD") and a number (either float or integer, I can parse either way) and I need to format this number to a currency string using the currency code. For example, `124.3222` and "USD" should create the string "$124.32".

I can create a `Currency` instance using `Currency.getInstance(String)`, which gives me the symbol and some other information. However, it does not provide any way to format the number as a string. On the other side of the problem, `NumberFormat` contains several static methods that return a `NumberFormat` instance capable of doing what I need (e.g. `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`).

The problem with `NumberFormat` is they are all centered around either the default locale, or a passed-in Locale. Given the nature of this app, *locale is meaningless*. There is no correlation between locale and the currency I need to format as a string. I can use neither the default locale, nor do I have any sort of locale identifier ISO value. All I have is the currency code.

It seems like I'm so close yet so far. There is (in my opinion) an odd disconnect between `Currency` and the `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance`. `Currency` can parse a currency code but not locale and cannot format strings, while `Locale` cannot parse a currency code but can format strings. Am I missing something here?

Edit: I should clarify that I can manually format the number using the symbol and decimal count provided by `Currency` instance, but I don't see how to figure out where to put the symbol in the string. At any rate, it seems like I should use the built-in currency formatting whenever possible.

Comment: From my interpretation of linked answer in [How to get NumberFormat instance from currency code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777956/295004) it appears that currency formatting is locale specific (i.e. decimal separator is different between Ireland and Italy).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered there is a `setCurrency()` method on `NumberFormat`. So what I am doing is calling `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` so I get a formatter for my locale, and then calling `setCurrency()` on it for the currency I need to format. This seems to do what I need.