# Better way to Format Input Money editText

Tags: android

I have an editText, I input value is $ 19000. But I want display in the editText is $ 19.000.

How can I do this ? thank all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a Float Value with the device currency format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131922/how-to-format-a-float-value-with-the-device-currency-format)

Answer (score 0):

Try DecimalFormat class

```
myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.###");
editText.setText(myFormatter.format(value));
```

For more info about format patterns you could visit 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html