# How to get the current locale (API level 24)?

Tags: android, locale, android-7.0-nougat

I was doing this way:

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale
```

[`Configuration.locale`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#locale) is deprecated if target is 24. So I made this change:

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)
```

Now it says that it's only for `minSdkVersion` 24, so I cannot use it because my min target is lower.

What's the right method?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Check which version you're running on and fallback to the deprecated solution:

```
Locale locale;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
} else {
    locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Locale.getDefault()`, which is the Java standard way of getting the current `Locale`.

Comment: This will only return the locale specified in the system settings. Many apps have their own language selector functionality. If that is the case, then the answer from @Egor is preferred.

Comment: If you select the locale manually, you should call Locale.setDefault()

Comment: This is very important, because otherwise Java libraries won't pick up the correct Locale correctly.

Comment: Peter states that some apps have their own language selector.  If they do, they should call Locale.setDefault as Ken states. So once again this solution will work. This should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one-liner that uses the [`ConfigurationCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/os/ConfigurationCompat) class:

```java
ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(context.getResources().getConfiguration()).get(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it should be the accepted answer: Minimal and without warnings.

Answer (score 3):

In `Configuration.java`, there is:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @deprecated Do not set or read this directly. Use {@link #getLocales()} and
 * {@link #setLocales(LocaleList)}. If only the primary locale is needed,
 * <code>getLocales().get(0)</code> is now the preferred accessor.
 */
@Deprecated public Locale locale;
...
configOut.mLocaleList = LocaleList.forLanguageTags(localesStr);
configOut.locale = configOut.mLocaleList.get(0);
```

So basically using `locale` basically returns the *primary* locale the user sets. The accept answer does exactly the same as reading `locale` directly.

However this locale isn't necessarily the one used when getting resources. It might be the user's secondary locale if the primary locale isn't available.

Here's a more correct version:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
Locale locale = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N
        ? resources.getConfiguration().getLocales()
            .getFirstMatch(resources.getAssets().getLocales())
        : resources.getConfiguration().locale;
```