# what to use instead of the deprecated locale

Tags: android, localization

I am trying to return the locale in my app with this line of code:

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

The *minSdkVersion* is 15 and compiling with 24. But `locale` is deprecated, does it affect my app efficiency?

Is there any other 'not deprecated' way to retrieve the locale?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current locale (API level 24)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267213/how-to-get-the-current-locale-api-level-24)

Comment: I mean if this deprecated local affect my app  efficiency

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are compiling with API 24 or above you should do this. Still it will show deprecated for lower one but you can ignore that.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    locale = getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
} else {
    locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly the answer that I wanted :)

Comment: Warning: N returns a list of locales, and loading strings will try to fallback to the next locale if there are no resources available. So just looking at the first one might be meaningless.