# How are these two calls to get the locale different?

Tags: android, localization

On Android, why are the following calls to get the locale different?

```
Locale.getDefault()
```

and

```
getResources().getConfiguration().locale
```

Comment: `Locale.getDefault()` is the standard way of getting the current locale in Java, and the `getResources().getConfiguration().locale` is the Android one but it is deprecated since API 24

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657747/why-does-android-have-its-own-way-to-get-the-current-locale/10671512#10671512)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locale selected on the device when the **app was launched** is the default locale returned by:

```
Locale.getDefault()
```

The locale **currently selected** on the device is the current locale (can be different from the default locale if the user changed the setting after the app launch) returned by:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().locale
```