# In xamarin, how to get the current language of the device for Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

How could I get the current language of the device in Xamarin (for Android)?

Got the language with `context.Resources.Configuration.Locale.Language`

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @TronicZomB yes I do not know in Xamarin how to use something like Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()

Comment: got the language with context.Resources.Configuration.Locale.Language

Answer (score 31):

Here's a cross platform version I use. Obviously you can pull whatever property you need from `CurrentUICulture`.

```
return CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

Maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: `using System.Globalization;` Mind that there have been occasional bugs with this.

Comment: @Wtower errr What bug?? Seriously this important for my app!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be what you are looking for:
http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aSystem.Globalization.RegionInfo

The RegionInfo class appears to have access for various ways to read that language information and use in your comparisons.

Based on this question, I went to the Xamarin documentation looking for the answer:
[Get the current language in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device)

Comment: Thanks Martin. The RegionInfo can get me some region names. I have got the current language by context.Resources.Configuration.Locale.Language.