# How to Block admob ads for Country

Tags: android, admob, ads

I do not want to show my admob  ads on my android app for a particular country. And is it possible to show other network ads for the blocked countries.
For example I want to block the users from Canada to see my admob ads, but want them to see ads from Airpush

Comment: You are using mediation?

Comment: P.S: I am new to admob

Comment: I guess i am not using mediation as when I click on "Ad Mediation Report" on my admob account, nothing appears

Comment: Well you have to decide if you want to use mediation or handle multiple networks manually. You can achieve this through the mediation interface at AdMob (although not very easily). I'm not sure exactly how you'd achieve it for manually handling networks, but you'd have to figure out where people are and then show the relevant network based on that, in code.

Comment: No, I am not using mediation.

Comment: @Ondkloss thanks for your reply, but can you please explain a little more and if possible with any example or a web link bcoz I am new to android and admob

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following:

```
if(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")){       
      YOUR ADMOB CODE     
}
```

For specific country look at following post: [Get the current language in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance to block ads by admob for a particular country.Its all done by few steps through code 
1.First try to get latitude and longitude of the user by using location manager
2.By using latitude and longitude we will get all the location details of user
3.Then create a list of countries(where ever you want to show ads).Then check user is in list of countries or not before 
(adview).loadAd(adrequest);
4.if you are loading ads in different activities take a boolean variable and make it as true based upon that boolean variable simply show ads