# Best practices for long text and format(terms & conditions) for different languages?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to create an activity for "Terms & Conditions" with support for different languages, but this is a long text document with several headers, paragraphs, points... which varies for each different language. So I think that having a strings.xml document for each language is not enough because each language "Terms & Conditions" has a different number of paragraphs, and specific layout for each language too. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

What will be the best approach for this requirement? Do I need to use a different fragment for each language(I don't like this option too much)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I normally show these files in a WebView, as separate html files. such as assets/terms-en.htm, assets/terms-de.htm, ...)

Comment: Thank you. I had not thought of that option.

Comment: Forgot to mention, as GreenFox pointed out: "and getting the current locale to append the language to the string indicating which file to open".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best approach with that is to create multiple `web pages` one for each language to be supported by your app and create a condition or your `Activity` that will test what language is being used by the device then load the appropriate `WebView` you need for that certain language. Hope it helps.

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

This will return a `String` value the language used on the device.

For more info about getting the language refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device)

Comment: Thank you. I had not thought of that option. Seems to be easy to implement and to maintain.