# libGDX, printing non-western fonts

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, arabic, chinese-locale

I'm in the middle of finishing my libGDX android game and I have problems with making localizations.

I want my game to be localized in Polish, English, Arabic and Chinese. To do this, I'm using libgdx I18NBundle which works perfectly fine. I have no problems with the former 2, they print very well with my BitmapFont(I've made it through Hiero).

I have completely no idea how to render the latter 2. Hiero doesn't seem to be capable of generating bitmaps from non-western fonts, and trying Gdx freetype extension left me even more confused(printing western symbols didn't work - another characters where showing and when I was trying to print Chinese/Arabic characters all I got was blank space).

Here's the second part of the question. Let's assume that I/we managed to achieve working font rendering. It's quite obvious that I'm going to need 3 fonts(Polish/English, Chinese and Arabic). I have to somehow detect system's language and then load proper font. Loading proper font doesn't seem like a big problem, the problem is, how I could detect the language(not whole locale).

Comment: i had the same problem , arabic is showing blank how did you fix that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hiero generates bitmap font for non-western fonts. I generated several Cyrillic bitmap fonts for my games. And I tried several arabic fonts from this [page](http://www.free-fonts.com/arabic) just now - all work pretty well. Probably you should ask another question with more detailed description of your problems with Hiero.
2. You can use method `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device)) in your `AndroidLauncher` class to get current language on device at runtime.

Then your should decide what language from your localizations you will use and pass this info to the main game class.

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    String sysLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    String i18nLang;
    if ((sysLang == "en") || (sysLang == "de")) {
        i18nLang = "en";
    } else if (...) {...}

    initialize(new MyGame(i18nLang), config);
}
```

Comment: You're right, Arabic works like charm. Any idea what to do with Chinese? Thanks for the solution for the second problem.

Comment: What exactly the problem with chinese fonts?

Answer (score 0):

If you select the font file manually, it will work. Apparently the non-western fonts in the default System list won't work in Hiero.

[image]