# Change android app language when Phone language is changed from Settings

Tags: android, android-studio, localization

i want to change my app string language, when language from settings is changed.

Like, right now it's english.
When I siwtch to hindi language from settings, the text in my android app should also be in hindi.

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create `values-xx` where "xx"is any language code like "en", "fr", "sp", "ar" .... and so on
2. create an xml with name of `string.xml` in the same folder.
3. create string in that xml

   `<string name="welcome">write in the language which you put as the language code</string`

Answer (score 3):

You shoul this site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

You must create values folders in res folder for localization.And you must create string.xml in your values folders.  For example:

values-tr for Turkish

values-fr for French

Answer (score 2):

values-hi/strings.xml

```
<string name="welcome">स्वागतम</string>
<string name="email">ईमेल पता</string>
<string name="password">पासवर्ड</string>
<string name="login">लॉगिन</string>
<string name="signup">खाता नहीं है? साइन अप करें</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

to get the device language for your device.(e.g en)

then make a switch to swap between ur "string" Values in ur app.(values/string.xml)

reference:
[Get the current language in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device)

quote:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()       ---> en      
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()   ---> eng 
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()        ---> US 
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()    ---> USA 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry() ---> United States 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName()    ---> English (United States) 
Locale.getDefault().toString()          ---> en_US
```