# If the language is english then use an another link than if it's german

Tags: android

how does the if condition look like?

```
if(Locale.getDefault().equals("English")){
    Log.i("Language","Englisch");
} else if(Locale.getDefault().equals("Deutsch")){
    Log.i("Language","Deutsch");
}
```

This won't work

Comment: Dont recreate wheel again. Just create file `strings.xml` in `res/values-de` so when you call `getString(R.string.hellow_world)` android will check what is system language and will try load from proper folder in your app. More info here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Locale.getDefault()` will return a `static` `Locale` Object, not a `String`. So calling `Locale.getDefault().equals("English")` will not work.

Try this:

```
String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

if (language.equals("en"))
{
    // Use English link
}
else if (language.equals("de"))
{
    // Use German link
}
```

> public String getLanguage ()
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Returns the language code for this Locale or the
>   empty string if no language was set.

Or:

```
String language = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

if (language.equals("English"))
{
    // Use English link
}
else if (...) { ....
```

> public final String getDisplayLanguage ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Equivalent to
>
> getDisplayLanguage(Locale.getDefault()).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23168383/3558874) are other possibilities:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()       ---> en      
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()   ---> eng 
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()        ---> US 
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()    ---> USA 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry() ---> United States 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName()    ---> English (United States) 
Locale.getDefault().toString()          ---> en_US
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()---> English
```

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

Comment: I want to use an another link from a webservice, if the language is different. So:

if(Language == English){
use the english link
} else if(Language == German) {
use the german link
}

And now i ask myself, how will the if condition looks like, anyone an example?

Comment: @FabASP See my edit. Do not use `==` for comparing `String` objects. Use `.equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Locale.getDefault` returns a `Locale`, not a `String`. If you want to know more about that locale you call `getLanguage` and `getCountry` on the `Locale`. Look up ISO code for language and country.
2. Usually, in android you solve something like this by different resources. Under `res/values-en/` and `res/values-de/` you can define language specific strings.