# Android getString() loads wrong resource

Tags: android, locale

I have this method in a class (normal class not `activity`)

```
    public String getTitle(Context context) {
      Log.d(TAG, Locale.getDefault().toString() + ", " + context.getString(R.string.title));
    return context.getString(R.string.title);
  }
```

When I call this method from `activity` passing context `(getApplicationContext())` the log prints (ar, Categories)
I double checked `strings` in xml and there are english and arabic word
so how come? locale is arabic and it returns english resource.

Comment: Is device default language is Arabic?

Comment: Check your title string present in both string xml

Comment: Device default lang is English

Comment: As I mentioned I double checked strings in xml

Answer (score 0):

**Add a folder in res  , named it `values-ar` . Create a `string.xml` file inside that folder  .  Put your title there as below .**

```
  <string name="title">arbic word</string>
```

**If your locale is set to arbic than You can get  your resouce String using below code .**

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.title);
```

Comment: This is what I did exactly and still return English resource only.
And when I transfer it to activity it runs well

Comment: Did you set the locale programatically ?

Comment: Try to change the language  from your phone setting and get back to your application.

Comment: For setting locale programatically - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android/43938564#43938564 

For Getting your current locale languaage  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device