# How know if language of Google Settings is downloaded

Tags: android, google-play-services

I need to check in my application before to do an action if the user has downloaded his language, for example English or Spanish. How I do this programmatically?

[image]

Comment: If I understand you right, you would like to get the language used by the application then there is a lot of possibilities in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device) like `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();`. Some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23168383/8342742) were to get the language in a specific device not the application itself.

Comment: Sorry, I needn't to know what is the language used by the application, I need to know if the language is downloaded in the device like I show in the image where you can see "Download languages" from "Google Settings > Offline speech recognition". Do you know some way to do this? Thank you for your answer.