# How to get the CURRENT device language in Android?

Tags: android, locale

This question has already been asked by different users, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device). But nevertheless, I need to repeat it as the provided answers do not help to get the CURRENT device language. My test device is in German language and the app in English. I try to get the current device language as follows:

- `Log.i("Language", Locale.getDefault().language)`
- `Log.i("displayLanguage", Locale.getDefault().displayLanguage)`

and both methods return:

- `I/Language: en`
- `I/displayLanguage: English`

which is not true. It should return something like this:

- `I/Language: de`
- `I/displayLanguage: Deutsch`

Do I do something wrong or there is a different way to get it done?

Comment: "and the app in English" -- what does this mean, in programming terms?

Comment: Actually, I use English language in 'strings.xml'. Therefore, the app language is in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current device language by simply calling

Java

```
ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration());
```

Kotlin

```
ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration)
```