# Why does my android app not using localized resource file?

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I am trying to use localized "strings.xml"s.

I created a strings.xml under "res/values-zh". However, my app somehow only use "res/values/strings.xml".

I checked the language using the following code:

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "default lang = " + Locale.getDefault().language)
Log.d("MainActivity", "resources.configuration.locale.language = " + resources.configuration.locale.language)
Log.d("MainActivity", "resources.configuration.locale = " + resources.configuration.locale)
```

and the result is:

```
2019-04-22 21:53:08.182 9431-9431/com.example.myandriod D/MainActivity: default lang = zh
2019-04-22 21:53:08.182 9431-9431/com.example.myandriod D/MainActivity: resources.configuration.locale.language = zh
2019-04-22 21:53:08.182 9431-9431/com.example.myandriod D/MainActivity: resources.configuration.locale = zh_HK_#Hant
```

What did I do wrong?

---

**Update:**

After some more googling, it seems this is a problem only occurs for Chinese. "res/values-zh/strings.xml" no longer works since Andriod 7.0, it must be changed to "res/values-zh-rHK/strings.xml" or "res/values-zh-rTW/strings.xml".

I still don't fully understand why it is so. For those who are interested, see https://gist.github.com/amake/0ac7724681ac1c178c6f95a5b09f03ce#new-locales-vs-old-locales-chinese

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021578/3395198

Comment: Is it `app\src\main\res\values-zh` (not `debug\...`)? Thanks to @IntelliJAmiya, I also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32393409/2914140.

Comment: @CoolMind Yes, it is. The file is created using Andriod Studio, so it can't go wrong